# Assign/bind the result of for clause?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to change `let $key := //COLNAME` to something like `let $key := {for $k in $keys return <s>{$k},</s>}`? `{for $k in $keys return <s>{$k},</s>}` is used in a lot of places so it will make the code clearer.

```
select @sql = @PrimaryKeyXml.query('
let $keys := //COLNAME return
<s>
ALTER TABLE ##keys ADD primary key ({for $k in $keys return <s>{$k},</s>});
</s>').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

BTW, does SQL Server 2014 xquery has string join function now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something *very* like it, yes:

```
let $key := for $k in $keys return <s>{$k}</s>
```

(i.e. lose the braces).

The `for` expression is an expression, and the value it denotes can be the value of a variable.